# What can I do to avoid declaring event handler names in more than one class in a WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, mvp

I am working on a WinForms application using the Model View Presenter pattern.  Every time I declare an event handler to be raised in the View I end up also declaring it in my Presenter class because it has to handle the event.

```
    // Code in the View Class:
//Note: Here is the declaration I am duplicating in every class that 
//handles the raising of the event (i.e. ProductSaveButtonEventRaised)

public event EventHandler ProductSaveButtonEventRaised;

private void SaveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ProductSaveButtonEventRaised!= null) //Check if any subscribed )
      {
        ProductSaveButtonEventRaised(this, eventArgs); // Notify all subscribers
      }
}

// Code in the Presenter Class:
// Note: Here the EventHandler declaration (ProductSaveButtonEventRaised)
// is repeated same as in the View. Is there another way to do this
// Other than duplicating the declaration in every class that needs to
// handle the event?:

public event EventHandler ProductSaveButtonEventRaised;

private void SubscribeEvents()
{
  _view.ProductSaveButtonEventRaised += new EventHandler(OnProductSaveButtonEventRaised);
}


private void OnProductSaveButtonEventRaised(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Event is raised again from the Presenter so it is forwarded to another
//Presenter which is the class that created this Presenter

  if (ProductSaveButtonEventRaised!= null) //Check if any subscribed )
      {
        ProductSaveButtonEventRaised(this, eventArgs); // Notify all subscribers
      }
}
```

Other than creating some kind of parent class for both classes to share and inherit the event declarations, what else can I do so I don't declare the event handlers more than once to cover classes that need to handle the events raised by the View?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Event declaration is different from the method (event handler) which you create to handle the the event. What's the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Event  handler should be in all associated class. that is not bad practice. while separate event declaration should be there in all classes which do have something to notify to all subscriber. And your concern will be solved if you try MVVM pattern (where model's event can be listened by both view and view-model)

Comment: Every class (publisher) which raises the event should contain the event declaration and every class (subscriber) which is going to subscribe to the event, should attach have an event handler method to the event of the publisher.

Comment: Wait a bit everybody. I am updating the code sample. I should of reworded the case to say it is the name of the event I am trying to avoid having declared in multiple places where one place raises it and other places listen and handle it. Sample will show soon.

Comment: @Robertcode why you need to declare that event in `Presenter Class` are you raising that event in `Presenter Class` class to, or just listening (subscribing) that event there.

Comment: @Amit Yes I am raising the event again in the Presenter so it is forwarded to another Presenter which created the current Presenter. I have updated to code to show this now.

Comment: @Robertcode is any of your View and Presenter class inherit some other class? coz in such case inheriting a base class which holds and event will be imposible

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for that. but I would surely suggest you keep doing what you are doing than what is alternate (which i have created) - as it is more clear code.

***This answer is just to show how it can be done.
I have made up this example so it may not look realistic***

Answer :

you can have a Base class which holds and raise events, both View and Presenter class can inherit this class (if any of your view or presenter class is already inheriting some other class, you cannot implement below logic)

```
public class BaseEventClass
{
  public string Name;
  public event EventHandler ProductSaveButtonEventRaised;
  public void RaiseAnEvent(BaseEventClass thisObj)
  {
    if (ProductSaveButtonEventRaised != null)
    {
        ProductSaveButtonEventRaised(thisObj, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
}

public class ViewClass : BaseEventClass
{
  public void LogicWhichRaiseAnEvent(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
    base.RaiseAnEvent(this);
  }
}

public class PresenterClass : BaseEventClass
{
  public void LogicWhichRaiseAnEvent(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
    base.RaiseAnEvent(this);
  }
}
```

and your calling logic which raise event and listening event will be something like below.

```
public static void Main()
{
    ViewClass v = new ViewClass();
    v.ProductSaveButtonEventRaised += ViewEventHandler;
    v.LogicWhichRaiseAnEvent("view");

    PresenterClass p = new PresenterClass();
    p.ProductSaveButtonEventRaised += PresenterEventHandler;
    p.LogicWhichRaiseAnEvent("presenter");
}

static void ViewEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((ViewClass)sender).Name);
}
static void PresenterEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(((PresenterClass)sender).Name);
}
```

Side Note : here I have made `Name` property in Base class so by looking out of `Name` property you can be sure, that event is of properly raised.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that events are not like regular objects. You cannot pass them to other classes to subscribe to them nor can you expose them as properties. You could however turn them into observables using [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) so you can. It is [designed](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#Should) for use cases like this.

To show the capabilities see this example:

```
public class View
{
    public event EventHandler ProductSaveButtonEventRaised; 
}

public class Presenter
{
    // Obervables are first class citizens, meaning you can pass them around or expose them as a property
    public IObservable<EventPattern<EventArgs>> ProductSavedEvents { get; private set;}             

    public Presenter(View view)
    {
        // Turn a regular event into an Observable
        ProductSavedEvents = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, EventArgs>(
                h => view.ProductSaveButtonEventRaised += h,
                h => view.ProductSaveButtonEventRaised -= h);
    }
}

public class PresenterCreator
{
    Presenter presenter = new Presenter(new View());

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        // Act on a save button event
        presenter.ProductSavedEvents.Subscribe(@event => Console.WriteLine(@event));

        var otherConsumer = new OtherConsumer(presenter.ProductSavedEvents);
    }
}

public class OtherConsumer
{
    // You can pass observables just like any other object. Can't do that with events
    public OtherConsumer(IObservable<EventPattern<EventArgs>> ProductSavedEvents)
    {
        // Act on a save button event
        ProductSavedEvents.Subscribe(@event => Console.WriteLine(@event));
    }
}
```